# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver after creating a jar

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I've established a database connection in my program but after creating a jar program it is throwing an

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

It looks like program don't see jdbc driver which I have installed and added to artifact:

[image]

I've tried changing a versions changing link looking for class name in JDBC but I've found same one that I've used before which worked in intelij but not in jar

There is a code that I'm using for connection

```java
package howareyoufeeling.database;

import java.sql.*;

public class DatabaseOperations {
    static Statement statement;

    public static void connectWithAzureDatabase() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String connectionUrl =
                "jdbc:sqlserver://howareyoufeeling.database.windows.net:1433;" +
                        "database=HowAreYouFeeling;" +
                        "user=wikimmax@howareyoufeeling;password=********;" +
                        "encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;" +
                        "hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;";
        try {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
            System.out.println("Successfull DB connection " + connection.getSchema());
            statement = connection.createStatement();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
    public static void sendDataQuery(String query){
        try {
            statement.execute(query);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

It looks like dependency is not in jar file but it is i checked it by decompiling and file size matches that includes a driver

Please help

Comment: Are you using Gradle or Maven to manage dependencies?

Comment: I'm using maven

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been solved.
The main wrong thing there was that I've tried to build a jar as application not as as Javafx app and database jar file was inside my build jar

Answer (score 0):

It's a packaging issue if you get that exception at runtime.

Your executable JAR needs to have all the dependencies built inside it.  There's a Maven plugin that can do it for you.

I'd recommend moving your database configuration outside of code so you can modify it more easily.

Comment: What do you mean by moving Database configuration outside ? plus this is strange because i've also tried adding jdbc directly do library as a jar in this case it should compile.

Comment: If I was writing this app in Spring Boot the configuration of the data source would be done in application.yml.  I'd use a Hikari data source connection pool.  I would not be writing your DatabaseUtils class at all.